# Installation issues

Tags: commerce, installation

So, to preface, I'm a complete novice when it comes to web development.  I've never done it before, but my boss wants an e-commerce site built in Drupal 8.  So, I'm following the steps listed in the Drupal Commerce 2.x installation.  Composer needs a little finagling to get working, but I manage it.

I run the "composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev" string, then attempt to import the site in Acquia Dev Desktop 2.  The result: "Does not appear to be a valid Drupal root folder.  There must be one or more folders in 'sites' containing settings.php."  I've tried copying the settings.php file from a known good Drupal 8 testSite I've built, but all that does is uninstall Commerce 2.x when I load the site.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you pointing Acquia to /path/to/project? It needs to /path/to/project/web if so

Comment: Yeah, I'm pointing at the /project/web folder.

Comment: My approach was: first I installed Drupal8 using Acquia Dev Desktop using the distribution. Then I opened my command line prompt and changed directory to the root of my Drupal8 installation and used composer to install Commerce and other modules. Hope this helps.